# Invalid nonce kraken

Tags: kraken.com

I am getting `{"error":["EAPI:Invalid nonce"]}` while calling https://api.kraken.com/0/private/AddOrder end point.

passing following params in form of json:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.accumulate("pair", "XXBT");
            jsonObject.accumulate("type ", "sell");
            jsonObject.accumulate("ordertype ", "market");
            jsonObject.accumulate("price", "2");
            jsonObject.accumulate("volume", "1");
```

Setting API-Key and API-Sign as well.

nonce = String.valueOf(System.nanoTime());

Generating nonce using above logic. Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try increase option `Nonce Window` to 5000-10000. You can find this option [here](https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001148023-What-is-a-Nonce-Window-).

Comment: A bit more explanation: It's important if you send requests simultaneously, because they can be delivered in unexpected order, but if you use sequence of `async` calls it can work with 0 nonce.

Comment: @DenisKolodin can you say more details. What's the `async`?